# In Crystal Reports, how to make a textobject grow upwards instead of downwards?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Is there some way to format a textobject to stick to the bottom of one section and then, depending on how much text that is filling it, make it grow upwards? Much like the behavior that we associate with vertical alignment. 
As far as I know, vertical-alignment:bottom (or similar) does not exist in Crystal Reports.

Is there a way to accomplish this by code, formatting formulas or some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to achieve the same effect by

- splitting the existing section into
  two subsections
- placing the growable field as the only field in the first subsection,
  and all other fields in the second
  subsection
- in the section expert, checking the "Underlay Following Sections" option
  for the first subsection.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works partially. 
Let's say I have 3 sections. s1 contains some text that is static. s2 contains the growable field and s3 contains a barcode. The height of the report cannot change. When doing like you suggested s3 follows s2 and the size of the report changes. Is there a way to keep s2 where it is? Similar to CSS position:absolute ?

Comment: @Jobe, it sounds as though you want the barcode to appear as the last thing on the page, with the growable field directly above it - in which case, the best way to do it would be to put both the growable field and the barcode into the page footer section. (It should not be necessary to divide the page footer into subsections.)

Comment: @Mark Bannister, unfortunately by doing so the growable field will overflow the barcode below resulting in both fields being unreadable. Other ideas? :/ 
It is really strange that such a easy and usable designing feature is so hard to accomplish with Crystal.

Comment: @Jobe, try splitting the page footer into two subsections (one for the growable field and one for the barcode) and ensure that the "Underlay Following Sections" option is **not** checked for the first subsection.

Comment: @Mark Bannister, now the growable field didnt grow even though the field has "Can grow" checked, unamusing, since the page cannot grow and the textfield doesnt grow over to another section one would think it would push its section upwards when growing, instead it doesnt grow at all.

Comment: @Jobe, the following seems to work: leave the barcode in the page footer, put the growable object in the report footer and check the "Print at bottom of page" option in the section expert for the report footer section.

Comment: @Mark Bannister, firstly, thank you for your patience in helping me its greatly appreciated. When I ad the growable field in the "report footer"-section, no text show up in the report preview in that section. Why do yo thing that is?
The barcode, however, shows up fine in the "page footer"-section.

Comment: @Jobe, the report footer section only appears at the end of the report, not the end of every page - I was assuming your report was only 1 page long. If you check the last page of your report, you should see the growable field in there - it appears there in the report I wrote in CR 10. If you have more than one page in your report, add a report group and put the growable field in the group footer (which also needs to be set to "Print at bottom of page") rather than in the report footer.

Comment: The report is only one page, but now when you mention it, the printer spits out an extra empty page when I print. :/ I have to check that. 

Anyhow, Looking at my question and your answer I realize that you actually answer the question. I should have been more detailed in the beginning.

Comment: Hmm, My report is meant to print on a label that is 80mm wide and 60mm tall (3,14 inches wide and 2,36 inches tall). Depending on how I specify my printer paper size crystal generates a bunch of extra pages, repeating my label (saying page: 1/1+ ) I found my report footer on the last page.  However, Im not able to make it fit on one single page :(

Comment: Actually, when taking the report live in my .net application, it did only one page and solution by Mark Bannister worked flawlessly. Thank you Mark!

Comment: I love it when a plan comes together! :)

Answer (score 1):

Put the field on the report twice.  Suppress one if it's short, supress the other if it's long.

Answer (score 0):

I just found workaround to this 
add carriage return chr(13) before text depends on text length

```
If Len < 25
Chr(13) + Chr(13) + Text
else if Len < 50
char(13) + Text 
....
```

and so on